# Reversing a Doubly Linked List with member function

Tags: c++, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to reverse a doubly linked list. According to other questions on stack overflow and the web this is the proper method to reverse a doubly linked list; swapping the `next` and `back` pointers of every node. For some reason it's not working for me and I can't debug it because XCode 6 has the entire debug menu grayed out. The reverse function is at the bottom of dll.cpp.  Heres my code:

dll.h:

```
#ifndef dll_h
#define dll_h
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <class ItemType>
struct NodeType
{
    ItemType info;
    NodeType* next;
    NodeType* back;
};


template <class ItemType>
class DoublyLinkedList
{
public:
    DoublyLinkedList();     // Class constructor.
    ~DoublyLinkedList();    // Class destructor.

    ////////// implement these functions //////////
    DoublyLinkedList(DoublyLinkedList<ItemType>& );
    void InsertItem(ItemType item);
    void DeleteItem(ItemType item);
    void reverseDoublyLinkedList();


    void FindItem(NodeType<ItemType>* listData, ItemType item, NodeType<ItemType>*& location, bool& found);
    int LengthIs() const;
    void MakeEmpty();
    void RetrieveItem(ItemType& item, bool& found);
    void ResetList();
    void GetNextItem(ItemType& item);

private:
    NodeType<ItemType>* listData;
    int length;
    NodeType<ItemType>* currentPos;
};
#endif
```

dll.cpp:

```
#include "DLL.h"
template<class ItemType>
DoublyLinkedList<ItemType>::DoublyLinkedList()
{
    listData = NULL;
    length =0;
    currentPos = NULL;

}
template<class ItemType>
void DoublyLinkedList<ItemType>::FindItem(NodeType<ItemType>* listData, ItemType item,
                                          NodeType<ItemType>*& location, bool& found)
// Assumption: ItemType is a type for which the operators "<" and
//  "==" are defined-either an appropriate built-in type or a
//  class that overloads these operations.
// Pre:  List is not empty.
// Post: If there is an element someItem whose key matches item's
//       key, then found = true; otherwise, found = false.
//       If found, location contains the address of someItem;
//       otherwise, location contains the address of the logical
//       successor of item.
{
    bool moreToSearch = true;

    location = listData;
    found = false;
    while (moreToSearch && !found)
    {
        if (item < location->info)
            moreToSearch = false;
        else if (item == location->info)
            found = true;
        else
        {
            location = location->next;
            moreToSearch = (location != NULL);
        }
    }
}


template <class ItemType>
int DoublyLinkedList<ItemType>::LengthIs() const
{
    return length;
}

template <class ItemType>
void DoublyLinkedList<ItemType>::MakeEmpty()
// Post: List is empty; all items have been deallocated.
{
    NodeType<ItemType>* tempPtr;

    while (listData != NULL)
    {
        tempPtr = listData;
        listData = listData->next;
        delete tempPtr;
    }
    length = 0;
}

template <class ItemType>
void DoublyLinkedList<ItemType>::ResetList()
{
    currentPos = NULL;
}

template <class ItemType>
void DoublyLinkedList<ItemType>::GetNextItem(ItemType& item)
{
    if (currentPos == NULL)
        currentPos = listData;
    else
        currentPos = currentPos->next;
    item = currentPos->info;
}
template <class ItemType>
void DoublyLinkedList<ItemType>::RetrieveItem(ItemType& item,
                                              bool& found)
{
    bool moreToSearch;
    NodeType<ItemType>* location;

    location = listData;
    found = false;
    moreToSearch = (location != NULL);

    while (moreToSearch && !found)
    {
        if (location->info < item)
        {
            location = location->next;
            moreToSearch = (location != NULL);
        }
        else if (item == location->info)
        {
            found = true;
            item = location->info;
        }
        else
            moreToSearch = false;
    }
}

template <class ItemType>
DoublyLinkedList<ItemType>:: ~DoublyLinkedList()    // Class destructor.
{
    MakeEmpty();
}

template <class ItemType>
void DoublyLinkedList<ItemType>::InsertItem(ItemType item)
{
    NodeType<ItemType>* node = new NodeType<ItemType>;
    node->info = item;
    if(!length)
    {
        listData = node;
        node->next = NULL;
        node->back = NULL;
        length++;
        return;
    }
    NodeType<ItemType>* temp =listData;
    if(temp->next == NULL)
    {
        if(temp->info < item)
        {
            node->next = NULL;
            node->back = temp;
            temp->next = node;
        }
        else
        {
            node->next = temp;
            node->back = NULL;
            temp->back = node;
        }
        length++;
        return;
    }
    while(1)
    {
        if(temp->info > item)
        {
            node->next = temp;
            node->back = temp->back;
            if(temp->back != NULL)
            {
                node->back->next = node;
            }
            if(temp->back == NULL)
                listData = node;
            node->back = temp->back;
            length++;
            return;
        }
        else if(temp->next == NULL)
        {
            node->next = NULL;
            node->back = temp;
            temp->next = node;
            length++;
            return;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}


template <class ItemType>
void DoublyLinkedList<ItemType>::DeleteItem(ItemType item)
{
    NodeType<ItemType>* node = listData;
    if(node == NULL)
        return;
    while(node != NULL && node->info != item)
        node = node->next;
    if(node == NULL)
        return;
    if(node->back != NULL)
        node->back->next = node->next;
    if(node->next != NULL)
        node->next->back = node->back;
    delete node;
    length--;
}

template <class ItemType>
DoublyLinkedList<ItemType>::DoublyLinkedList(DoublyLinkedList<ItemType>& original)
{
    length = 0;
    currentPos = NULL;
    listData = NULL;
    NodeType<ItemType>* copy = original.listData;
    while(copy != NULL)
    {
        InsertItem(copy->info);
        copy = copy->next;
    }
}

template<class ItemType>
void DoublyLinkedList<ItemType>::reverseDoublyLinkedList()
{
    if(listData == NULL || listData->next == NULL)
        return;
    NodeType<ItemType>* node = listData;

    while(node!=NULL)
    {
        swap(node->next, node->back);

        listData = node;

        node = node->back;
    }
    currentPos = NULL;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "dll.h"
#include "dll.cpp"

int main()
{
    DoublyLinkedList<int> s;
    s.InsertItem(3);
    s.InsertItem(4);
    s.InsertItem(1);
    s.DeleteItem(2);
    s.DeleteItem(4);
    cout<<"Length of s: "<<s.LengthIs()<<endl;
    DoublyLinkedList<int> t = s;
    cout<<"Length of t: "<<t.LengthIs()<<endl;
    t.InsertItem(5);
    t.InsertItem(13);
    t.InsertItem(10);
    t.InsertItem(-3);
    int a;
    t.ResetList();
    for(int i=0;i<t.LengthIs();i++)
    {
        t.GetNextItem(a);
        cout<<"Item #"<<i<<": "<<a<<endl;
    }
    cout<<endl;
    t.reverseDoublyLinkedList();
    t.ResetList();
    for(int i=0;i<t.LengthIs();i++)
    {
        t.GetNextItem(a);
        cout<<"Item #"<<i<<": "<<a<<endl;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Unrelated but if anyone could tell me why XCode 6.1 wont let me debug on my new Macbook Pro that would be helpful too.

EDIT: 
Output:

```
Length of s: 2
Length of t: 2
Item #0: -3
Item #1: 1
Item #2: 3
Item #3: 5
Item #4: 10
Item #5: 13

Item #0: 13
Item #1: 5
Item #2: 3
Item #3: 1
Program ended with exit code: 9
```

At the end it crashes on member function GetNextItem() on line `item = currentPos->info;`.

Comment: @JerryCoffin that wouldn't do it, as you still have to use "prev" function to move down the list (instead of "next"), so you need to swap "prev" and "next" for each node also. Why would one want to reverse a doubly linked list (except for a homework) is beyond my understanding.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin I am doing this for a lab report. The question says to develop a member function that reversed the list. If I just moved the head pointer to tail my list would only be 'reversed' if I also started traversing the list using back instead of next in other member functions. At application level GetNextItem() would still get items in the same order.

Comment: @Hauzron - You could simplify things by having a `Node*` member that represents the last node in the linked list.  Then starting from this node, you can reverse the list easily.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I suppose that would work but I'd have to edit the header file and a lot of other member functions to include that now. I feel like I'm really close to being done. I just have to fix this problem.

btw thanks for your help on my last question. It got locked so I couldn't respond.

Comment: @Hauzron - Since you say you can't debug it, please define `it's not working for me`.  Is it crashing?  Is it reversing half the list?  Is it reversing everything until it hits the last node? etc... BTW, you still didn't implement `operator =` for the linked list.  I can break your `main` function easily by doing this: `DoublyLinkedList<int> t; t = s;`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Sorry I forgot that bit. I added to my question, the output I'm getting and where exactly it crashes. The reversed list skips #10 and crashes before reaching the end.

The reason I didn't overload operator= is because the question doesn't tell us to overload it. This is just a lab report. I was only supposed to implement InsertItem(), DeleteItem(), the copy constructor and reverseDoublyLinkedList(). The rest of the code was given to me.

Comment: @Hauzron - As to operator =, consider the purpose of your main() function.  Is it supposed to test your implementation?  If so, it fails very easily if you happen to do those two simple lines of code.  So whether the question asked you to overload `=` is not really the point.  You could have easily run smack into this issue by slightly changing your main() function, and you would then post on SO "why is my main() function crashing?"

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The main function is just supposed to test the functions I'm supposed to implement. So long as I don't use the assignment operator in my main program it'll be fine.

Comment: @Hauzron - You are not testing correctly if you claim your main() function has to be in cement and can't be changed.  The way you debug a problem is to see if another sequence of calls or data changes things.  If you did that, you will mysteriously see that the reverse() works correctly.  For example, insert 1, 2, 3, 4, and then 5 starting from an empty list.  Bingo, reverse works.  Now figure out why the sequence in your main() function doesn't work, given this information.  Maybe your InsertItem has bugs?

Comment: Thanks! I think that can help me pinpoint the bug.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you so much. The problem _was_ in InsertItem() after all. All I had to do was change the second `node->back = temp->back;` to `temp->back = node;`. Yes, the second. Apparently I updated `node->back` a second time when I actually meant to update             `temp->back`. As a result some of by `back` pointers weren't pointing at the proper nodes and it wasn't until the reverse function that actually used back pointers that this affected my program. 

I was just staring at my reverse function code the entire time. Guess I learnt a thing or two about debugging now.

Comment: @Hauzron - The `InsertItem` is overly complicated.  It should be very simple.  I will post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has to do with your `InsertItem`.  Right now, it is overly complicated.

You are attempting to insert an item in increasing order.  So the easiest thing to do is take a pair of nodes, and see if the item goes in-between the pair.  Here is an easier implementation:

```
template <class ItemType>
void DoublyLinkedList<ItemType>::InsertItem(ItemType item)
{
    NodeType<ItemType>* node = new NodeType<ItemType>;
    node->info = item;
    if (!length)
    {
        listData = node;
        node->next = NULL;
        node->back = NULL;
        length++;
        return;
    }

    NodeType<ItemType>* temp = listData;
    while (temp)
    {
        // get the next node
        NodeType<ItemType>* nextNode = temp->next;

        // make sure we have a pair of nodes
        if (nextNode)
        {
            // test for inbetween
            if (item >= temp->info && item <= nextNode->info)
            {
                // set the pointers and return
                // make sure we set the node in-between the temp and nextNode
                temp->next = node;
                nextNode->back = node;

               // now set node to point to temp (back), and nextNode (next)
               // for the in-between to link correctly
                node->next = nextNode;
                node->back = temp;

               // increase the length and get out
                ++length;
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
           // we're at the last node, so only place for this is at the back
           // set the pointers and return
            temp->next = node;
            node->back = temp;

            // last node, so make sure it points to NULL as next
            node->next = NULL;

            // increase length and get out
            ++length;
            return;
        }
        // go to next node and get next pair   
        temp = nextNode;
    }
}
```

Now, this works.  Can it be better?  Probably, but the point is that it is easy to understand what is going on.

If you drew on paper what is needed to be done, the above is probably closest to what you would draw on paper, i.e. get two nodes, see if the item goes in-between the two nodes, if not, get the next pair of nodes, etc...